# How to declare data members that are objects of any type in a class

Tags: c++, templates

In this piece I'm trying to declare in Class B a list that can hold objects of Class A of any type, such as A<int>, A<double>, A<float>. I intend to add A objects to the list during runtime:

```cpp
#include <list>

template <class T> class A {};

class B {
    template<class T> std::list<A<T>*> objects;
};
```

It seems like making a list like this should work but compiling it gives an error:

> Line 6: error: data member 'objects' cannot be a member template
>
> compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work and how I can fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not know the type before hand"?  When do you know the type?  C++ is a statically typed programming language:  all types must be known at compile-time.

Comment: @james I don't know what kind of objects of type A (A<int>, A<float>, ..) that will be passed into Class B and added to the objects list during runtime.

Comment: That's fine, Dpham, but how will you find out? For example, `std::vector` doesn't know what type it will hold, either, but it learns its type by being given a type parameter any time someone mentions the template. How will your `B` class know what type of `A` it has been given? Write some code demonstrating how your code is intended to be used, and that can help shape the interface you need to give it.

Comment: @Rob I'm doing something like this: void createObjectAndAddToList(OBJECT_TYPE type) {
    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_INT:
     B::instance()->addToList(new A<int>());
 case TYPE_FLOAT:
     B::instance()->addToList(new A<float>());
            break;
 case TYPE_DOUBLE: ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's just not how C++ works. If you want to group different objects together, they need to have at least *some* relation. Being instantiations of the same class template doesn't imply that they are related, they're completely distinct types. If you want a list of `A<T>*`s, better make a list of base-class pointers and forward operations through virtual functions:

```
class A_base{
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual ~A_base() { }
};

template<class T>
class A : public A_base{
public:
  void foo(){
    // ...
  }
};

class B{
  std::list<A_base*> objects;
};
```

Comment: Probably better to use a list of smart pointers or a Boost ptr_list, but +1. Short of Boost.Any, this is the closest C++ gets to a heterogeneous container.

Answer (score 7):

Member variables aren't allowed to be templates. Only member *functions* can be templates. You'll have to templatize the enclosing class `B` instead:

```
template <class T>
class B {
  std::list<A<T>*> objects;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you **cannot have template variables**. Only option to declare a member data is to make the class template:

```
template<class T>
class B {
    std::list<A<T>*> objects;
};
```

Comment: This fixes the compilation error but I don't want B to be a template class.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, type erasure might be an option. [On the Tension Between Object-Oriented and Generic Programming in C++](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) is my favorite write-up on the subject.

In a nutshell, you convert the static dispatch enabled by the templates into dynamic dispatch through a custom inheritance tree you setup on the fly.  Instead of storing `A<T>`, you create a new type that has the common interface you desire, and using some template/inhertiance voodoo this new type stores an `A<T>` without actually exposing the `T`.  So `A<int>` and `A<double>` and `A<A<std::list<A<int> > > >` and `some_type_that_looks_like_A_but_really_isnt` all reduce down to a single type.

But you have to have a common interface, independant of that parameter.  If you can't, things get more difficult.

[Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html) is a good example, as is `std::shared_ptr` [which uses type erasure to remember how to delete the pointer passed to it even in the face of non-polymorphic inheritance].

Comment: I appreciate the link. It really helps explain in depth the problem and how to fix it. I also like the simplicity of the code posted by @Xeo.

Answer (score 0):

Make `B` class template just like you've made `A` a class template:

```
template<class T> 
class B {
    std::list<A<T>*> objects;
};
```