# C++ class with template member variable

Tags: c++, templates, types

I am trying to solve a programming problem that consists of an object (call it Diagram), that contains several parameters. Each parameter (the Parameter class) can be one of several types: int, double, complex, string - to name a few.

So my first instinct was to define my Diagram class as having a vector of template parameters, which would look like this.

```
class Diagram
{
private:
    std::vector<Parameter<T> > v;
};
```

This doesn't compile, and I understand why. So, based on the recommendations on this page [How to declare data members that are objects of any type in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261375/how-to-declare-data-members-that-are-objects-of-any-type-in-a-class), I modified my code to look like:

```
class ParameterBase
{
public:
    virtual void setValue() = 0;
    virtual ~ParameterBase() { }
};


template <typename T>
class Parameter : public ParameterBase
{
public:
    void setValue() // I want this to be 
                    // void setValue(const T & val)
    {
        // I want this to be 
        // value = val;
    }

private:
    T value;
};

class Diagram
{
public:
    std::vector<ParameterBase *> v;
    int type;
};
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to call the setValue function with an appropriate templated parameter. It is not possible to have a templated parameter in the ParameterBase abstract base class. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I don't have the flexibility to use boost::any.

Comment: You can't virtually set the parameter to any value, you either need to cast to the appropriate `Parameter<T>` type or remove the object and create a new one

Comment: Don't use a setter, use a constructor, then you can always do `v.push_back(new Parameter<My>(my));`

Comment: Why not just convert them to a common type and convert back when needed? That's how things like this are usually done.

Comment: @KillianDS I'm not sure I understand what you mean ... Do you mean using void* and casting?

Comment: @GeneBushuyev The setter was just one example of an interface function. There are others as well. Besides, I may have to edit the parameter's value after construction.

Comment: @endbegin - then you are out of luck, you erased the type information, so you can either use virtual functions (but they must have the same signature), or an ugly unmaintainable `if(dynamic_cast<Parameter<My1>*>(base)) ...; else ...`

Comment: The declaration `virtual void setValue() = 0;` implies this is something you can do to any parameter, even if you don't know its type, but how would that make sense?

Comment: I think you are trying to be "too clever". Once you create an object of type Parameter<string>, it is fixed to that type. Since you have to know which you want it to be for you to later do something to this object, using virtual functions is definitely not the right solution. 

It's not quite clear what you are actually trying to do, but I think if you explain what your goal is, in a bigger picture, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You got very close.  I added a few bits because they're handy

```
class ParameterBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ParameterBase() {}
    template<class T> const T& get() const; //to be implimented after Parameter
    template<class T, class U> void setValue(const U& rhs); //to be implimented after Parameter
};

template <typename T>
class Parameter : public ParameterBase
{
public:
    Parameter(const T& rhs) :value(rhs) {}
    const T& get() const {return value;}
    void setValue(const T& rhs) {value=rhs;}    
private:
    T value;
};

//Here's the trick: dynamic_cast rather than virtual
template<class T> const T& ParameterBase::get() const
{ return dynamic_cast<const Parameter<T>&>(*this).get(); }
template<class T, class U> void ParameterBase::setValue(const U& rhs)
{ return dynamic_cast<Parameter<T>&>(*this).setValue(rhs); }

class Diagram
{
public:
    std::vector<ParameterBase*> v;
    int type;
};
```

Diagram can then do stuff like these:

```
Parameter<std::string> p1("Hello");
v.push_back(&p1);
std::cout << v[0]->get<std::string>(); //read the string
v[0]->set<std::string>("BANANA"); //set the string to something else
v[0]->get<int>(); //throws a std::bad_cast exception
```

It looks like your intent is to store resource-owning pointers in the vector.  If so, be careful to make `Diagram` have the correct destructor, and make it non-copy-constructable, and non-copy-assignable.

Comment: Had to make some minor changes to your test code, but this works well.  Thanks.

Comment: @endbegin: What changes did you have to make?  If I have errors in my answer, I'll fix them up for people who have similar issues in the future.

Comment: @endbegin: as a note, this is almost exactly how `boost::any` works.

Comment: Nothing major: Initialized a diagram type `Diagram d;` and a parameter 
`Parameter<std::string> p1("Hello");` To add to the vector, I did `d.v.push_back(&p1);` and to set the string, I did `d.v[0]->setValue<std::string>("BANANA");`

Comment: Was wondering what changes I'd have to make to the interface if I wanted a `vector<ParameterBase>` instead of a `vector<ParameterBase *>` ...

Comment: @endbegin: it's not safe to store polymorphic types in a container, so you'd have to come up with something _completely_ different, and _far_ more complicated.  I wouldn't go there.

Comment: @MooingDuck Why would a ´static_cast´ not work in your example shown above ? As I see it this would have worked fine, so just wondering the choice of using a ´dynamic_cast´ ?

Answer (score 6):

The bellow implementation uses a few C++11 features but you will be
able to pick them apart.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Parameter
{
private:
  class ParameterBase {
  public:
    virtual ~ParameterBase() {}
    virtual ParameterBase* copy() = 0;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
  };

  template <typename T>
  class ParameterModel : public ParameterBase {
  public:
    // take by value so we simply move twice, if movable
    ParameterModel(const T& t) : t(t) {}
    ParameterModel(T&& t) : t(t) {}
    void foo() { t.foo(); }
    ParameterModel* copy() { return new ParameterModel(*this); }
  private:
    T t;
  };

public:
  template <typename T>
  Parameter(T&& t) 
    : pp(new ParameterModel< typename std::remove_reference<T>::type >(std::forward<T>(t))) {}

  // Movable and Copyable only
  Parameter(Parameter&&) = default;
  Parameter& operator=(Parameter&&) = default;

  Parameter(const Parameter& other) : pp(other.pp->copy()) {};
  Parameter operator=(const Parameter& other) {
    pp.reset(other.pp->copy());
    return *this;
  };

  // members

  void foo() { pp->foo(); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<ParameterBase> pp;
};


class Diagram
{
public:
  std::vector<Parameter> v;
  int type;
};

struct X {
  void foo() {}
};

struct Y {
  void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
  Diagram d;
  d.v.emplace_back(X()); // int

  // parameters are copyable and can be reassigned even with different
  // impls
  Parameter p = d.v.back();

  Parameter other((Y()));
  other = p;
  return 0;
}
```

What does this code do? It hides the fact that we use inheritance to
implement parameters from our users. All they should need to know is
that we require a member function called `foo`. These requirements are
expressed in our `ParameterBase`. You need to identify these
requirements and add the to `ParameterBase`.  This is basically a more
restrictive `boost::any`.

It is also quite close to what is described in [Sean Parent's value semantics](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/12/value-semantics-and-concepts-based-polymorphism-sean-parent) talk.

Comment: I feel like the `Parameter` class is not needed, and you provide no (clear) way to do assignment, reassignment, or get at the hidden data. :(  But since you have it, why did you make it non-copiable?

Comment: This makes it awfully easy to accidentally store a reference to temporary in a `Diagram`.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks. I thought about that while coding. Added `remove_reference`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a little behind the (C++) times, and I am constrained by VS2008. Will spend some time trying to absorb this.

Comment: @MooingDuck Adding a virtual `copy` to `ParameterBase` would be necessary. The code is unfortunately already more complex than I would like it to be. Feel free to add it. Maybe it would be better for OP to also remove the rvalue references.

Comment: @endbegin I edited the code so ParameterS are also copyable and reassignable. This essentially is the same as a `setValue` function.

Comment: @pmr: Yeah, sorry, I forgot it would require a virtual copy.  In that case the deleted copy makes sense.  Sorry for suggesting that you make the answer more confusing :(

Comment: How would you implement the `get()` function in the question with this solution?

Comment: In this case, @lukegravitt, `get()` would likely be implemented by the internal worker classes, with `Parameter` providing a simple pass-through that roughly looks like `pp.get()->get()` or `pp->get()`.