# How to fill as generic as possible std::vector from json with templates in C++ (11)?

Tags: c++, json, templates, c++11, stdvector

i have data saved as a json file and i want to reload it. Due to having them as json they are strings after loading (i use boost property tree). i have written a function for reinterpret a std::vector. It works fine untill i compile with a call to this function. then the compiler dont know how to use this code correctly:

```
template<typename T_vecType>
std::vector<T_vecType> getValues1D(std::string key)
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;

    // determine type
    std::string type;
    type = ptLoad.get(key + ".type", "d");

std::vector<std::string> out;

BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v,
              ptLoad.get_child(key + ".value" ))
{
    out.push_back(v.second.data());
}

if(type == "f")
    {
        std::vector<T_vecType> resultf;

        for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i) {
            resultf.push_back( std::stof( out[i].c_str() ) );
        }

        return resultf;
    }
else if(type == "i")
    {
        std::vector<T_vecType> resulti;

        for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i) {
            resulti.push_back( std::stoi( out[i].c_str() ) );
        }

        return resulti;
    }
```

The problem is that i need for every datatype a different interpretation of the string. that is the reason why i am trying it in this ugly way. maybe i call like this:

```
getValuesVector<int>("vecData");
```

The compiler is complaining that he cannot put a float into int, because he things he will execute the first if statement. i have also tried this:

```
if( typeid(T_vecType) == typeid(float) && type == "f")
...
if( typeid(T_vecType) == typeid(int) && type == "h")
```

Comment: Is this a template function? Do you pass `type` as a parameter? You can't have the same function returning two different types, template or not. We need to see more of the code. How is the function declared and how is it called?

Comment: Typically for JSON object storage you have an object that will store the JSON value and provide a number of different methods for accessing the JSON value.  So you may store the JSON value as a string however when you use the value, you will call a method to provide the specific data type that you want.  Take a look at some of the specifications an libraries such as [Universal Binary JSON Specification](http://ubjson.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have put more information to the code part.

Comment: I am not sure what it is that you are trying to do so more information about what you want to accomplish and why would be good.  What I think you want to do is to read in JSON text and parse it creating the various kinds of objects described by the text.  You will then use these objects in various operations.  You want to have each object named so that you can locate the object.  Since objects can be composed of other objects, you want to use some kind of a tree such that the value for a particular object is found by traversing the tree locating the object at a leaf or end point.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing the big picture. Your issue probably lies in your design, but I'll first explain why your current approach doesn't work.

The problem here is that you are trying to use a template method before knowing the type it's supposed to return. What ends up happening is that you get a method returning `vector<int>` which may return `vector<float>` and a method returning `vector<float>` which may return `vector<int>`. This just won't work.

A simple solution is to determine the type before calling your method and then call the appropriate version:

```
template<typename T_vecType>
std::vector<T_vecType> getValues1D(std::string key)
{
    std::vector<std::string> out;

    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, ptLoad.get_child(key + ".value"))
    {
        out.push_back(v.second.data());
    }

    std::vector<T_vecType> result;

    for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i) 
    {
        result.push_back(std::stof(out[i].c_str()));
    }

    return result;
}

// Then somewhere in code
if (type == "f")
{
    std::vector<float> resultf = getValues1D<float>(key);
}
else if (type == "i")
{
    std::vector<int> resulti = getValues1D<int>(key);
}
```

This just shows how to use templates, but it doesn't necessarily solve your overall problem. The actual solution will probably look more like the answer to this question: [C++ class with template member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980157/c-class-with-template-member-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a rough example of a class that stores a value as a `std::string` and then provides conversion functions for most of the standard JSON types.  The approach is to have a class that stores individual JSON object values as a string and then provides conversions from the string to the different target types.

This is more of an example to show an approach.

In the main there are examples of using the JSON value class including storing the JSON values into a `std::map` with a key and then retrieving them.  Since I am using Visual Studio 2005 the conversions are done without the C++11 string conversion functions so that would be something for you to fix up.

This would seem to be a more appropriate approach than using templates since this approach provides for a class that provides some of the capabilities of a non-typed language.  You can improve the flexibility of the class by providing additional methods.

```
// JsonValue.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

// Our standard JSON object storage which stores the
// JSON value as a text string and provides various methods
// to do data conversion from the text to the desired type.
class JsonValue {
public:
    JsonValue ();
    JsonValue (std::string &textValue);
    JsonValue (char *textValue);
    JsonValue (int iValue) { *this = iValue; }

    void    SetValue (std::string &textValue);
    std::string ToString ();

    // various conversion functions
    operator int () { return ToInt (); }
    operator float () { return atof (m_textValue.c_str()); }
    operator double () { return atof (m_textValue.c_str()); }
    operator bool () { return (m_textValue == "true") ? true : (ToInt() == 0 ? false : true); }

    // some basic operators
    JsonValue & operator = (const JsonValue &rhs) {if (this != &rhs) {this->m_textValue = rhs.m_textValue; } return *this; }
    JsonValue & operator = (const int iValue) {char buf[32]; _itoa_s (iValue, buf, sizeof(buf), 10); this->m_textValue = std::string(buf); return *this; }

    JsonValue operator + (const int iValue) { return JsonValue (ToInt() + iValue); }
    std::string m_textValue;

private:
    const int  ToInt () { return atoi (m_textValue.c_str()); }
};

// binary addition operator to add int plus a JsonValue as an integer.
int operator + (int iValue, JsonValue &json)
{
    return iValue + static_cast<int>(json);
}

// default constructor
JsonValue::JsonValue ()
{
}

// constructor from a std::string value
JsonValue::JsonValue (std::string &textValue)
{
    m_textValue = textValue;
}

// constructor from a char pointer (standard C string) value
JsonValue::JsonValue (char *textValue)
{
    m_textValue = std::string (textValue);
}

void JsonValue::SetValue (std::string &textValue)
{
    m_textValue = textValue;
}

std::string JsonValue::ToString ()
{
    return m_textValue;
}

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const JsonValue &json)
{
    // write obj to stream
    os << json.m_textValue;
    return os;
}

typedef std::map <std::string, JsonValue>  JsonMap;
typedef std::pair <std::string, JsonValue> JsonPair;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    JsonValue jj(std::string("12345"));
    JsonValue kk(237);

    JsonValue lll("-123");

    int  myLll = lll;
    int myI = jj;
    float myF = jj;

    jj = 5;
    jj = kk + 1;

    jj = 1 + kk;

    JsonMap myMap;

    myMap.insert (JsonPair(std::string("val1"), jj));
    jj.SetValue(std::string("99"));
    myMap.insert(JsonPair (std::string("val2"), jj));
    myMap.insert(JsonPair (std::string("val3"), kk));

    for (JsonMap::iterator v1 = myMap.begin(); v1 != myMap.end(); ++v1) {
        std::cout << v1->first << " maps to " << v1->second << std::endl;
        std::cout << "    int +3    " << v1->second + 3 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```