# C++ How to get a member from a templated derived class?

Tags: c++, list, templates, c++11, derived-class

*EDIT: This was incorrectly marked as duplicate. [C++ class with template member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980157/c-class-with-template-member-variable) has two answers, but neither one seems sufficient in this case. The first answer, you have to provide the templated type when calling the getter function. The second answer provides no return type.*

Using C++11, I need to store pointers to objects in a list:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<PropertyGroup> >  _properties;
```

The objects are from templated struct types, so to do that, I have a non-templated base struct:

```
struct PropertyGroup
{
    EntityId                    entityId;
    time_point<system_clock>    startTime;
    milliseconds                duration;
    bool                        started;
    bool                        cancelled;

    virtual void*                       GetStartValue() = 0;
    virtual void*                       GetTargetValue() = 0;
    virtual void*                       GetResultValue() = 0;
    virtual std::function<void(void*)>  GetCallback() = 0;
};
```

And a templated derived struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct TypedPropertyGroup : public PropertyGroup
{
    T                       startValue;
    T                       targetValue;
    T                       resultValue;
    std::function<void(T)>  callback;

    T GetStartValue() override { return &startValue; }
    T GetTargetValue() override { return &startValue; }
    T GetResultValue() override { return &startValue; }
    T GetCallBack() override { return &callback; }
};
```

TypedPropertyGroup has type templated members which I need to access when iterating through the list elsewhere (startValue, targetValue, resultValue, and callback).

I am not sure how to access the extra members from an iterator.

```
std::list<PropertyGroupPtr>::iterator iter = _properties.begin();

while (iter != _properties.end())
{
    std::shared_ptr<PropertyGroup> propertyGroup = *iter;

    // get the value of TypedPropertyGroup::startVale here?

    ++iter;
}
```

I saw in a post elsewhere that adding virtual functions for the base class is a way to access the derived class' members. There was no example given, and I'm not sure how to declare the virtual function in the base class to ignore the return type.

In the examples above, as far as I have got was to return void* in the base struct, and then return a pointer to the value. That won't work though.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas to be able to achieve this without the use of unions or boost::variant. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to be able to do with `GetStartValue()` if you don't know its type?

Comment: `T GetStartValue() override { return &startValue; }` Doesn't make sense to me. You are returning a `T*` but the return type says `T`.

Comment: I expect to call a templated function with the value. The function wilkl perform some calculations and then call the "callback" function pointer with a result.

Comment: Yes, I understand the return type if T*. I mentioned that the functions don't work. Declaring T* results in an error, for example: "Return type of virtual function 'GetStartValue' is a covariant with the return type of the function it overrides('int *' is not derived from void*).