# How to store a template as a member of a typical C++ class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I am using *C++ 14* where my code needs to build for *clang*, *gcc* & *Microsoft compiler*. I have a class like below

```
class MyClass {

public:

    AnotherClass    m_member_object;
    int             m_some_value_1;
    int             m_some_value_2;

    MyClass(const AnotherClass & another_object, int some_value_1, int some_value_1) {

        m_member_object = another_object;
        m_some_value_1 = some_value_1;
        m_some_value_1 = some_value_2;
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass & my_class_copy) {

        m_member_object = my_class_copy.m_member_object;
        m_some_value_1 = my_class_copy.m_some_value_1;
        m_some_value_2 = my_class_copy.m_some_value_2;
    }
};
```

I want to templatise `AnotherClass` which is member object (*or could be a pointer*) in `MyClass`. Trying to learn templates from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template), when I make `AnotherClass` like below,

```
template<typename T>
T  m_member_object;
```

Compiler complains that `member m_member_object is declared as a template`

**Question:**
How can I store a `template` type instead of `AnotherClass` & let the user code of `MyClass` define what type it wants to store in `MyClass`?

Comment: If you could use C++17, it has [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: When they say "member templates" they mean member functions. You need something like `template <class T> struct S{ T member; };` for a member object.

Comment: You can make `MyClass` a template, where `MyClass<T>` only holds a member object of type `T`. This is how all the standard library containers work.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/GzKSQ9

Comment: OT: don't implement a copy constructor that does the same as the default.

Comment: @AndreySemenov trying out the suggestion you made.

Comment: I cannot templatise `MyClass`. I am strictly looking for a way to templatise only the member that is `AnotherClass`. If its not possible then the answer is that it cant be done as per compiler rules. Trying out @AndreySemenov's suggestion

Comment: @IllegalSkillsException The suggestion of @AndreySemenov is to "templatise" `MyClass`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/7so3GZ i fixed example code. with c++17 you can use tamplate deduction

Comment: You can't store a template type because there is no such thing as template type. Templates are not types,  they are recipes to make types. You can't eat a recipe.

Comment: due to my less understanding of templates, I misunderstood. I think that @AndreySemenov's answer would work for me well.

Comment: It isn't clear how shared_ptr is related to any of this.

Comment: @n.m. not its not related at all. removing `shared_ptr` stuff from my comment

Comment: Another thing - if `MyClass` *could* store various things inside, what would `sizeof(MyClass)` be? That's one reason why you need to make it `sizeof(MyClass<T>)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare data members that are objects of any type in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261375/how-to-declare-data-members-that-are-objects-of-any-type-in-a-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of each member has to be the same throughout the class.

You have two choices:

- `MyClass` is *one* type, `m_member_object` is *one* type that boxes up all the required possible values, such as [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). You then have to deal with unboxing it and only ever doing type-appropriate things to it
- `MyClass` is *multiple* types, `m_member_object` is specific to each `MyClass`. This is typically done by making `MyClass` a template. You can `template <typename T> MyClass<T> : MyClassBase` and use virtual dispatch, which allows you to operate on one type in outside code, however you have to use some indirection (typically `std::unique_ptr<MyClassBase>`) to safely operate.

Comment: this is short but very well provides the information that I needed.